# When I select the options from the dropdown the button should be triggered automatically and produce the unique Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down and when I select one option from the dropdown the button has to be triggered automatically and it produces some unique id. I am not sure how the trigger can happen when we select the value from the dropdwon.
I have refered this link
[Auto trigger click on a button when selecting from dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217697/auto-trigger-click-on-a-button-when-selecting-from-dropdown-list)

but its not working and its not showing any error. I can see that its not going inside the button click function. can someone help me how to do the auto click when we select the dropdown option?
I am attacching the code here

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Send Email Invite">
        <form>
            <fieldset>               
                <label for="select1">Round Level</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select name="select1" class="form-control" id="select1" style="width:200px; height:30px;" required>
                        <option value="">Select the below option</option>
                        {% for each_round in round_names %}
                        <option value="{{each_round.round_id,each_round.round_name}}">{{each_round.round_name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <div class="valid-feedback">Valid</div>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" id="generateButton" style="display:none;" required>
                        <input id="generateUrl" value="generate url" size="40%" readonly />
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Generate URL" id="urlbutton"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div id="result">
                        <textarea name="rdesc" id="rdesc" style="width:200px; height:300px; display:none;"
                            required></textarea>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <script>
                    $("#select1").on('change', function () {
                        $("[name='select1']:submit").trigger("#urlbutton")
                        var dropdownValue = document.getElementById("select1");
                        var roundName = dropdownValue.options[dropdownValue.selectedIndex].value;

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'blah',
                            data: {
                                'blah': blah
                            },
                            success: function (results) {
                                $("#rdesc").show();
                                $("#rdesc").text(results.round_description);

                            }

                        })


                    })

                </script>

                <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>

        $("#urlbutton").click(function () {
            console.log("i am coming here");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'blah',
                data: {
                    'blah':blah
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var url_textbox = document.getElementById("generateUrl");
                    url_textbox.setAttribute('value', data.url);
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Hook the second AJAX call to the `submit` event of the `form` (instead of the `click` of the button) and then trigger that submit event whenever you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click the button programmatically like this.

On your select change click the button.

```
("#urlbutton").click()
```

Comment: I tried this $("#select1").on('change', function () {
                        $("[name='select1']:submit").click("#urlbutton") and its not working

Comment: Just use `$("#urlbutton").click()` without ` $("
 [name='select1']:submit")`

Comment: Thanks its working now. I need one more help. I want to show the generated url in the text box.  $("#generateUrl").show(); I tried in my ajax call,but its not visible.How should I do it?

Comment: add  this `$("#generateUrl").show();`  in ajax success , It should work. try this and let me know.